# Where to find Python package CPU architecture compatibility?

Tags: dependencies, cpu-architecture, pypi

Python packages that contain compiled code will sometimes not work on certain CPU architectures (x86, arm64 etc). This problem often pops up when you install Python dependencies on Raspberry Pi, Apple M1, M2 or M3 computers or Amazon ARM hardware.

I would like to find out whether a specific version of a package is compatible with a specific CPU architecture before actually installing it.

I don't see data for this on [The Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/).

My current strategy is

- read the PyPI page for the package
- search the GitHub issues for the package

This method is slow and imprecise (because it often is not version specific).

Is there somewhere I can look this up?
Is there an automated process I can run to check compatiblity?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, no way. Your way of looking things up is most probably the only meaningful. You could improve precision by running automatic compilation but that would be even slower. OTOH you could create a site that publishes such information for every version of every package (or at least popular packages); that would be a major improvement and a big achievement for Python world.

Comment: As a side product you could publish wheels for unusual architectures that are beyond the classic trio "Linux/MacOS/w32 on x64".